# rsnapshot wrongly filter getting added

Tags: linux, fedora, rsync, rsnapshot

I have following lines in rsnapshot.conf

```
snapshot_root   /mnt/T4Backup2T/Incremental-Backup
rsync_long_args --numeric-ids
exclude_file    /home/CD/CLPB/backup-files/rsnapshot/saraswathi.exclude
backup  /   localhost/fedora/   +rsync_long_args=--exclude /home --exclude /mnt --relative --delete --delete-excluded /
```

it is wrongly producing following lines (--filter option is not specified but still coming up)

```
/usr/bin/rsync -a --numeric-ids \
    --exclude-from=/home/CD/CLPB/backup-files/rsnapshot/saraswathi.exclude \
    --exclude /home --exclude /mnt --relative --delete --delete-excluded / \
    --filter=-/_/mnt/T4Backup2T/Incremental-Backup / \
    /mnt/T4Backup2T/Incremental-Backup/weekly.0/localhost/fedora/
```

There is no filter option in rsnapshot.conf but still it is getting produced, what could be misconfiguration?

Answer (score 2):

This happens to avoid snapshot_root getting sync again. As explained in the rsnapshot-program.pl

> If this backup point contains the snapshot root, add an exclude to
>   avoid backing up the snapshot root recursively. The exclude is
>   anchored (by virtue of the leading slash of
>   $config_vars{'snapshot_root'}) and applies to absolute paths (the "/"
>   modifier), so it should match the snapshot root and nothing else
>   regardless of --relative.

Comment: https://github.com/rsnapshot/rsnapshot/blob/master/rsnapshot-program.pl lines starting from 1117